# How can I decrypt a file using multiple threads at the same time using AES-CBC

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption

I currently try to decrypt a file using the `encrypt` package from pub.dev. So currently my app asks a password to the user, then it verifies if the password is valid and then the user can pick a file to decrypt, and this is the part where I want to multi-thread this operation. I have already tried to use this code:

```dart
  static void decryptImageBlocks(List<dynamic> args) async {
    Encrypter cipher = args[0];
    SendPort comPort = args[1];
    Map<int, Uint8List> blocks = args[2];

    for(MapEntry<int, Uint8List> block in blocks.entries) {
      comPort.send({block.key: cipher.decrypt(iv: IV.fromLength(16), Encrypted(block.value))});
    }
  }

  static List<Uint8List> splitEncrypted(Encrypted encrypted, int blockSize) {
    final bytes = encrypted.bytes;
    final numBlocks = (bytes.length / blockSize).ceil();

    final blocks = <Uint8List>[];
    for (var i = 0; i < numBlocks; i++) {
      final start = i * blockSize;
      final end = (i + 1) * blockSize;
      final block = bytes.sublist(
          start, end < bytes.length ? end : bytes.length);
      blocks.add(Uint8List.fromList(block));
    }
    return blocks;
  }

  static void decryptAndLoadImage(List<dynamic> args) async {
    final encryptionKey = args[0];
    final File fileToRead = args[1];
    final SendPort port = args[2];
    final ReceivePort decryptPort = ReceivePort();
    Encrypter cipher = Encrypter(AES(encryptionKey, mode: AESMode.cbc));
    Encrypted encryptedImage = Encrypted.fromBase64(fileToRead.readAsStringSync());
    List<Uint8List> blocks = splitEncrypted(encryptedImage, 16); // For CBC
    const int threadAmount = 1;
    int currentID = 0;
    List<Map<int, Uint8List>> assignedBlocks = List.filled(threadAmount, {});
    for(Uint8List block in blocks) {
      assignedBlocks[currentID % threadAmount][currentID] = block;
      currentID++;
    }
    for(Map<int, Uint8List> assignedBlockList in assignedBlocks) {
      await Isolate.spawn(decryptImageBlocks, [
        cipher,
        decryptPort.sendPort,
        assignedBlockList
      ]);
    }
    List<Uint8List> decryptedBlocks = [];
    decryptPort.listen((message) {
      Map<int, List<int>> msg = message;
      decryptedBlocks[msg.keys.first] = Uint8List.fromList(msg[msg.keys.first]!);
      if(decryptedBlocks.length == blocks.length) {
        Uint8List? finalImage;
        for(Uint8List decryptedBlock in decryptedBlocks) {
          if(finalImage == null) {
            finalImage = decryptedBlock;
            continue;
          }
          finalImage.addAll(decryptedBlock);
        }

        port.send(finalImage);
      }
    });
  }
```

Where you can ignore the `decryptAndLoadImage` method because it just assigns all the blocks to the threads run them, and compiles back the image. When I use this code I get this error: `Invalid argument(s): Invalid or corrupted pad block` So I think the split method is at fault here but I can't find any errors made inside of it. At the long therm I want this app to be really optimized for mobile so I need to economise on those heavy operations. What can I try next?

Comment: Unless the original data is encrypted with independent concatenated blocks of the size you're splitting it into, this won't work. Since encryption is typically NOT done by concatenating independently encrypted blocks, this scheme just won't work. If you have multiple files, decrypting the whole files in parallel would work fine. Encryption typically accumulates and uses information across the stream, so requires the contiguous sequence of blocks, so you can't split them up into separate threads.

Comment: While you can parallelize CBC decryption, it's a bit more complicated than it looks. For any subset of blocks you need to give it an IV. For the zero'th group, the IV is the overall IV. For any other group the IV is the last block of the previous ciphertext. Also, each block cannot be unpadded since it isn't then end of the complete message. So, all groups except the last need to be treated as unpadded, with only the last group being unpadded.

Comment: The data I decrypt is encrypted by my app too so I have full control over it, I just used the CBC cipher because it looked like one of the best for pictures, videos and all that kind of stuff

Comment: Note that encrypt just uses pointycastle that implements the AES rounds in software. You may get more mileage out of finding an FFI based implementation, accessing hardware AES round instructions. (I've sometimes achieved 100 times the speed of pointycastle that way.)

Comment: Using an FFI based implementation would be faster for sure. But this would make me implement those native AES round instructions for each platform and my program certainly needs more optimizations (7.65s on avg to load 2 Mo of data) but it doesn't need this x100 improvement because I will essentially read videos and if it can keep up between the data stream needed and the decrypting speed I am okay with it. My main idea for this code at first was to be easily able to load a stream from the blocks and being able to load the video and have a buffer if possible.

Comment: But I think I can just split the data at the initial encryption time, store the blocks using three base64 strings on different lines and assign the line to a thread, I think that it should do a usable work-around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**06/04/2023 EDIT**: My project has changed a lot since I answered my question, so I would like to say that for me the AES-CBC cipher **wasn't** suitable performance wise for my use, that's why I changed to an natively implemented package named [cryptography_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/cryptography_flutter) which relies on the [cryptography](https://pub.dev/packages/cryptography) package to work. So now as it is natively implemented, the decryption shouldn't be multithreaded as it doesn't run in a Dart isolate, so I wrote this class which **doesn't use any MAC**. In my case I couldn't use a MAC as I stored all my data directly in local files but if you would like to encrypt data for network use this could be an issue. So here's my new code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:cryptography/cryptography.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:life_chest/vault.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class SingleThreadedRecovery {
  static final cipher = Chacha20(macAlgorithm: MacAlgorithm.empty);
  static Future<Uint8List> loadAndDecryptFullFile(SecretKey encryptionKey, File fileToRead) async {
    return Uint8List.fromList(await cipher.decrypt(SecretBox(fileToRead.readAsBytesSync(), nonce: Uint8List(cipher.nonceLength), mac: Mac.empty), secretKey: encryptionKey));
  }

  static Stream<List<int>> loadAndDecryptFile(SecretKey encryptionKey, File fileToRead) {
    return cipher.decryptStream(fileToRead.openRead(), secretKey: encryptionKey, nonce: Uint8List(32), mac: Mac.empty);
  }

  static Future<Map<String, String>?> saveFiles(SecretKey encryptionKey, String vaultPath, {List<File>? filesToSave, String dialogTitle = 'Pick the files you want to add'}) async {
    if(filesToSave == null) {
      FilePickerResult? pickedFiles = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true, dialogTitle: dialogTitle);
      if(pickedFiles != null) {
        filesToSave = [
          for(PlatformFile file in pickedFiles.files)
            File(file.path!)
        ];
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }

    final Map<String, String> additionalFiles = {};

    for(File createdFile in filesToSave) {
      String fileName = md5RandomFileName();
      File fileToCreate = File(join(vaultPath, fileName));
      await fileToCreate.create(recursive: true);
      IOSink fileToCreateSink = fileToCreate.openWrite();
      try {
        final clearTextStream = createdFile.openRead();
        final encryptedStream = cipher.encryptStream(
          clearTextStream,
          secretKey: encryptionKey,
          nonce: Uint8List(cipher.nonceLength), onMac: (Mac mac) {}
        );
        await fileToCreateSink.addStream(encryptedStream);
      } finally {
        fileToCreateSink.close();
        additionalFiles[fileName] = basename(createdFile.path);
      }
    }
    return additionalFiles;
  }
}
```

**OLD ANSWER**

I finally implemented a way to do this:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class MultithreadedRecovery {
  static String md5RandomFileName() {
    final randomNumber = Random.secure().nextDouble();
    final randomBytes = utf8.encode(randomNumber.toString());
    final randomString = md5.convert(randomBytes).toString();
    return randomString;
  }

  static void _decryptFileBlock(List<dynamic> args) async {
    Encrypter cipher = args[0];
    SendPort comPort = args[1];
    Encrypted block = args[2];
    int blockID = args[3];

    comPort.send(MapEntry(blockID, Uint8List.fromList(cipher.decryptBytes(block, iv: IV.fromLength(16)))));
  }

  static void _startMultithreadedDecryption(List<dynamic> args) async {
    final Key encryptionKey = args[0];
    final File fileToRead = args[1];
    final SendPort port = args[2];
    final ReceivePort decryptPort = ReceivePort();
    Encrypter cipher = Encrypter(AES(encryptionKey, mode: AESMode.cbc));
    List<String> base64Blocks = fileToRead.readAsLinesSync();
    List<Encrypted> encryptedBlocks = List.generate(base64Blocks.length, (index) {
      return Encrypted.fromBase64(base64Blocks[index]);
    });

    for(Encrypted encryptedBlock in encryptedBlocks) {
      await Isolate.spawn(_decryptFileBlock, [
        cipher,
        decryptPort.sendPort,
        encryptedBlock,
        encryptedBlocks.indexOf(encryptedBlock)
      ]);
    }
    List<Uint8List> decryptedBlocks = List.generate(encryptedBlocks.length, (index) => Uint8List(0));
    int receivedBlocksAmount = 0;
    decryptPort.listen((message) {
      MapEntry<int, Uint8List> msg = message;
      decryptedBlocks[msg.key] = msg.value;
      receivedBlocksAmount++;
      if(receivedBlocksAmount == encryptedBlocks.length) {
        List<int>? finalFile;
        for(Uint8List decryptedRawBlock in decryptedBlocks) {
          List<int> decryptedBlock = decryptedRawBlock.toList();
          if(finalFile == null) {
            finalFile = decryptedBlock;
            continue;
          }
          finalFile.addAll(decryptedBlock);
        }

        port.send(Uint8List.fromList(finalFile!));
      }
    });
  }
  
  static Future<Uint8List> loadAndDecryptFile(Key encryptionKey, File fileToRead) async {
    ReceivePort dataPort = ReceivePort();
    Isolate.spawn(_startMultithreadedDecryption, [encryptionKey, fileToRead, dataPort.sendPort]);

    return await dataPort.first;
  }

  static List<List<T>> _splitList<T>(List<T> list, int numSublists) {
    int sublistLength = list.length ~/ numSublists;
    int remainingItems = list.length % numSublists;
    List<List<T>> sublists = [];
    int offset = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numSublists; i++) {
      int length = sublistLength + (i < remainingItems ? 1 : 0);
      sublists.add(list.sublist(offset, offset + length));
      offset += length;
    }
    return sublists;
  }
  
  static Future<Map<String, String>?> saveFilesForMultithreadedDecryption(Key encryptionKey, String vaultPath, [List<File> filesToSave = const [], String dialogTitle = 'Pick the files you want to add', int threadCount = 3, int blocksCount = 3]) async {
    if(filesToSave.isEmpty) {
      FilePickerResult? pickedFiles = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(allowMultiple: true, dialogTitle: dialogTitle);
      if(pickedFiles != null) {
        filesToSave = [
            for(PlatformFile file in pickedFiles.files)
              File(file.path!)
          ];
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }

    List<List<File>> assignableFiles = _splitList(filesToSave, threadCount);

    final ReceivePort port = ReceivePort();
    final Encrypter cipher = Encrypter(AES(encryptionKey, mode: AESMode.cbc));
    final Map<String, String> additionalFiles = {};
    int aliveThreads = threadCount;
    final Completer<void> completer = Completer<void>();

    Future<void> listenForMessages() async {
      await for (var message in port) {
        additionalFiles.addAll(message);
        aliveThreads--;
        if (aliveThreads == 0) {
          completer.complete();
          port.close();
        }
      }
    }

    listenForMessages();
    
    
    for(List<File> threadFiles in assignableFiles) {
      await Isolate.spawn(_saveAndEncryptFiles, [threadFiles, cipher, vaultPath, port.sendPort, blocksCount]);
    }

    await completer.future; // Wait for all the tasks to finish

    return additionalFiles;
  }

  static String _joinByNewLine(List<String> lines) {
    String finalString = '';

    for(String line in lines) {
      finalString += line;
      finalString += '\n';
    }
    finalString.trim();

    return finalString;
  }

  static void _saveAndEncryptFiles(List<dynamic> args) async {
    List<File> pickedFiles = args[0];
    Encrypter cipher = args[1];
    Map<String, String> additionalFiles = {};
    String vaultPath = args[2];
    SendPort port = args[3];
    int blocksAmount = args[4];
    for(File createdFile in pickedFiles) {
      String fileName = md5RandomFileName();
      File fileToCreate = File(join(vaultPath, fileName));
      await fileToCreate.create(recursive: true);
      List<List<int>> decryptedBlocks = _splitList(await createdFile.readAsBytes(), blocksAmount);
      List<String> encryptedBlocks = [];
      for(List<int> decryptedBlock in decryptedBlocks) {
        encryptedBlocks.add(cipher.encryptBytes(decryptedBlock, iv: IV.fromLength(16)).base64);
      }
      await fileToCreate.writeAsString(_joinByNewLine(encryptedBlocks));
      additionalFiles[fileName] = basename(createdFile.path);
    }
    port.send(additionalFiles);
  }
}
```

What this code does is that it encrypts the file into multiple blocks who gets decrypted in the amount of blocks created by the original encryption, **I would like to say that this code is NOT made for buffering the encrypted data** because there are so few blocks that can be read at the same time.